# How to prove this inequality (polynomials and e)

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials

Prove that:

$ x^{2019}e^{-x} \leq x^{2019} $

for every $ x \in [\frac{1}{e},1] $

Without using a calculator to figure out the bounds.

Tried to manipulate it but got pretty much nowhere.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: This is equivalent to $$e^{-x}\le1$$as long as $x^{2019}\gt0$

Comment: @PeterForeman which is equivalent to $x>0$...

Comment: @Szeto I was trying not to give the answer in a comment.

Comment: Oh guys i feel really stupid, Thanks a lot. I just realized how simple this is.

Comment: Are you sure this is the question? This is not just easy, it's trivial.

Comment: What @Deepak said: It really seems likely that you copied the problem wrong, because this is _so_ trivial (also because it's trivial for $x>0$, making the condition $x\in[1/e,]$ simply irrelevant.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your inequality is equivalent to $$x^{2019}(e^{-x}-1)\le 0$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to prove that $x^{2019}(1-e^{-x})\ge 0\forall x\in [1/e,1]$, since in this interval $x^{2019}\ge 0$ the condition is equivalent to $1-e^{-x}\ge 0\iff e^{-x}\le 1\iff e^x\ge 1\iff x\ge \ln (1)=0$ so you have thesis.